# Is it possible to replace internet connection with mobile hotspot while still retaining network topology (wifi router, DHCP, local LAN, etc)?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet, dhcp

ISP service has been interrupted and we do have hotspot available, but I'm hoping we can somehow just swap the internet connection source to the hotspot with as little disruption as possible to local network configurations?

I'm guessing it's a long shot to have that sort of modularity, but thought I'd at least ask and see if it might be possible, or something close to it?

We've got a network printer, a workstation, several smart lighting and surveillance devices, etc.; previously these were allocated IP reservations with the router acting as DHCP, and I'm not feeling confident about my phone having the capabilities to take over all (or even any) of that.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no.

In some edge cases you could get your router to behave as an AP client (and AP) and then tether its AP client to your phone hotspot, but this is a long shot for most routers.

If you think this is going to be a regular event, or you have spare hardware lying around, you may be able to configure another device as an AP Client, then connect its LAN port to the WAN port of your router and have it act as an AP Client for your hotspot.    Make sure the IP ranges you use are different.

Comment: So this would be hardware-dependent?  If it matters at all, my phone is a stock, unlocked KB2007 (OnePlus 8T+ 5G [TMO], on Verizon).  The ISP *was* AT&T (U-Verse) but due to other household circumstances there is a strong possibility of a change occurring in that respect.  Aside from the "mandatory" hardware that came with the ISP's service, I do have several spare modems and routers laying around gathering dust, including a Netgear R8500 (Nighthawk X8 AC5300) and an Arris SB6190 (DOCSIS3.0 SURFBoard).

Comment: Your phone does not matter (as long as it does hotspotting ).  I dont know that either of the routers you mentioned will work as a hotspot - you might be able to flash a version of dd-wrt on yhe R8500 and use that but it seems that router is not well supported and could land up bricked if you are unlucky. Do you have any other ethernet only routers that will work with dd-wrt?

Comment: I have several spare routers, but I don't know their capabilities or compatibilities with dd-wrt.  Also not sure if it matters, my wife has a hotspot device called an "Insego"?  I've yet to use it myself, but from the sound of it it sounds like it was meant to take on a similar role as routers, I wonder if I might be able to use that instead?

Comment: It may well be that your Insego device (never heard of one) can act as an AP client if it has an ethernet interface.  If you don't have what it takes to look up your device compatibility with dd-wrt (https://dd-wrt.com/support/router-database/) I'll leave this here.